# PHP If-Statements not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have tried using this as an if statement, but it wont work.  It says incorrect pass and wrong stuff.  What is wrong?

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
$server = $_POST['server'];
$room = $_POST['room'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if ($submit) {
  if ($server && $status && $room && $password) {
    if ($password == "o") {
      echo "Done";
    } else {
      echo "all fields";
    }
  } else {
  }
  echo "incorrect pass";
} else {
  echo "submit";
}
```

Comment: What is the value of $_POST['submit'] ??

Comment: Your logic will be wrong if any of those fields are numeric and accept `0` as a value. That'll get translated to a boolean false and fail your 'validation'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little difficult to see what you're trying to do.

```
} else {

}
echo "incorrect pass";
```

That should be *inside* the braces for one. This should stress the importance of proper code formatting and indentation.

I think it should also be switched with the other else block, like so:

```
if ($server && $status && $room && $password) {
    if ($password == "o") {
        echo "Done";
    } else {
        echo "incorrect pass";
    }
} else {
    echo "all fields";
}
```

Another thing, I always use `isset()` to check if the `$_POST` values are, in fact, set.

Comment: lol? did you even make change? There is no possible way it could be saying Done and incorrect pass.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be valid code, you have more `}`s than `{`s.

Assuming there are a few conditions about that code that account for the brace mismatch, your

```
echo "incorrect pass";
```

happens **after** the closing brace of the 'if ($submit) {`condition, and therefor will run *regardless* of the value of`$submit`.